How to log the peak memory usage of Jupyter Notebook
I have a Jupyter Notebook on cloud for a long-running job. The job uses considerable RAM, thus I assign a high-memory (and expensive) machine for it.
However, I know that the maximum RAM required is more or less constant among runs, so I want to know the RAM usage at its peak and switch to a cheaper machine with just the right amount of RAM. But since the job takes long time to run, I do not want to sit there and watch, nor via trial-and-error with machines of different specs.
Is there a way to keep a log of the peak RAM used of the job?

Did you try https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter-resource-usage ? Did you look at the comments for 'Logging an plotting memory usage from jupyter notebook' and try any of that?

Also, keep in mind that Jupyter Notebooks are made for interactive usage. There's a lot of coverage out there saying what you are finding is to be expected because they aren't made for long running computational efforts and you should be using traditional approaches to manage long running tasks, such as running behind screen or tmux, and using top, using ps, using psutil, etc.. See here. You should have no problem as you are in fact already using a Python script it seems.

@Wayne the notebook is a spec of the company, not mine. If you have an answer, please kindly click the "Answer Question" button and put it down, many thanks.
